# Generating multivariate normal random numbers with zero covariances in matlab

Tags: matlab, statistics, sampling

Suppose to generate a n-dim normal random number with distribution N(u, diag(sigma_1^2, ..., sigma_n^2) in Matlab, where u is a vertical vector.

There are two ways.

```
randn(n,1).*[sigma_1, ..., sigma_n]' + u;

mvnrnd(u', diag(sigma_1^2, ..., sigma_n^2))';
```

I think they are both correct. But I wonder if there is some preference of one over the other based on some reasons? I ask this question, because I saw another person always choose the first way, while I choose the second without having thought about it yet.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: `mvnrnd` is in the stats toolbox and `randn` isn't - so it you are worried about toolbox compatibility then use `randn`.

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent methods. Personally, I would prefer the second option because it's one function that can be used to generate this sort of data for arbitrarily-shaped arrays. If all of a sudden you wanted a whole matrix of Gaussian values, you can get that more easily from the second function call, without doing any calls to `reshape()`. I also think the second example is easier to read because it relies on a built-in of Matlab's that has been ubiquitous  for a long time.

I suppose that if `n` is large, one could argue that it's inefficient to actually form `diag(sigma_1^2, ..., sigma_n^2)`. But if you're needing to make random draws from a matrix that large, then Matlab is already the wrong tool for the job and you should use Boost::Probability in C++, or perhaps SciPy / scikits.statsmodels in Python.

Answer (score 2):

If there are correlations between the random variables then the covariance matrix is not anymore diagonal. In such case you may use `mvnrnd` or use `randn` with Cholesky decompistion as following.

```
U = chol(SIGMA);
x = U'*randn(n,1);
```

Whenever possible, use basic functions instead of using toolbox functions. Basic function are faster and portable.

Comment: "Whenever possible, write your own code with basic functions instead of using toolbox functions." This is generally bad advice. Most toolbox functions are properly tested, well documented and correctly handle edge cases. You're better off sticking to these implementations unless you have a strong reason not to.

Comment: @MichaelKoval I accept that it was not a generally good advice! However, I would not call `mvnrnd` to generate random variables. Calling m-files makes MATLAB slower, and most checks inside those function are unecessary if you know your code. Moreover, using more than one toolbox will make the code quite expensive from licensing point of you. In general, if the project is not big and only one person does coding, then fancy functions and robust programming methods will not pay off the lost performance.